# Problem Binding to GridView HiddenField

Tags: list, gridview, data-binding, hiddenfield

EDIT: I added in the hf from the first reply that was pointed out.  This helped with a few other issues, but still did not fix the problem.

I am trying to bind a list to a gridview with a LOT of hidden fields (I'll only use 2 of the 50) for temporary holding so the user can create and delete multiple items without going back and forth to the database multiple times during creation.  I'm fine with binding to and recalling from the BoundFields; however, when I try to recall the hidden field values it comes back as null.  I may be having problems with the binding to the hidden fields.  Here's my code

ASP:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdOtherCarrier" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
<Columns>
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Sequence" DataField="Sequence"></asp:BoundField>
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Pay ID" DataField="PayID"></asp:BoundField>
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="Provider" DataField="Provider"></asp:BoundField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Actions">
                <ItemTemplate>  
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfInsuredLastName" Value="<%#Eval("InsuredLastName")%>" runat="server" />
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfInsuredFirstName" Value="<%#Eval("InsuredFirstName")%>" runat="server" />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

C# / code behind:

```
    protected void lblSubmitOtherCarrier_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<OtherCarrier> OCList = new List<OtherCarrier>();

        OtherCarrier OC;

 foreach (GridViewRow row in grdOtherCarrier.Rows)
        {
            if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                OC = new OtherCarrier();
                String Sequence = row.Cells[0].Text.ToString() ; // primary value
                String PayID = row.Cells[1].Text.ToString(); // primary value
                String Provider = row.Cells[2].Text.ToString();    // primary value

                HiddenField InsuredLastName = (HiddenField)row.FindControl("hfInsuredLastName");
                HiddenField InsuredFirstName = (HiddenField)row.FindControl("hfInsuredFirstName");

                OC.Sequence = Sequence;
                OC.PayID = PayID;
                OC.Provider = Provider;
                OC.InsuredLastname = InsuredLastName.Value.ToString();
                OC.InsuredFirstName = InsuredFirstName.Value.ToString();

                OCList.Add(OC);
            }
        }
        OC = new OtherCarrier();

        OC.Sequence = txtSequence.Text;
        OC.PayID = txtPayID.Text;
        OC.Provider = txtProvider.Text;
        OC.InsuredLastname = txtInsuredLastname.Text;
        OC.InsuredFirstName = txtInsuredFirstName.Text;
        OCList.Add(OC);

        TD.OtherCarrierList = OCList;

        grdOtherCarrier.DataSource = OCList;
        grdOtherCarrier.DataBind();

        mpeAddOtherCarrier.Hide();
        txtSequenceNo.Text = (grdOtherCarrier.Rows.Count + 1).ToString();
     }
```

When it gets to assigning the OC.InsuredLastname from the hidden field the hidden field is coming up as null value.  Either I'm not reading it correctly or it's not being written correctly.

Comment: Do you fill your hidden field values in client?

Answer (score 1):

so...

you are trying to find a control as

```
(HiddenField)row.FindControl("InsuredLastName");
```

as you can see, named `InsuredLastName` when you explicit say in the HTML that your control name is:

```
<asp:HiddenField 
    ID="hfInsuredLastName" 
    Value="<%#Eval("InsuredLastName")%>" 
    runat="server" />
```

named `hfInsuredLastName`

all you need to do is change the call to

```
(HiddenField)row.FindControl("hfInsuredLastName")
```

Comment: I added the hf to the fields and confirmed that they had correct names by copying and pasting the IDs from the HTML to the code behind and still encountered the same problem.  I'll update the code above to show this fix.